# Como integrar o KCFinder com o Laravel?

Tags: laravel, kcfinder

Estou fazendo um formulário onde o usuário pode inserir uma imagem juntamente com o texto. Procurando na internet achei o KCFinder que faz exatamente o que eu preciso. Integrei ele com o CKEditor e até aí tudo bem.
O problema é que estou desenvolvendo a aplicação com o Laravel, e quando tento fazer upload de imagem com o KCFinder, dá erro de rota, diz que não existe. Realmente a rota não existe, não sei como criar uma rota para a pasta do KCFinder (que está na pasta public da aplicação).
Alguém sabe como faz?

Comment: Na verdade o KCFinder tem um arquivo de configuração dentro dele. Você tem que alterar a URL lá. E depois você pode criar uma rota normal para upload das imagens.

Comment: @PeterParker, não estou sabendo como fazer a rota. As rotas que faço, normalmente são do tipo `Route::get('url', 'AlgumController@metodo');` ou `Route::get('url', function(){
  return algumacoisa;
});`

O que devo retornar na rota?

Comment: Certo. É isso mesmo. Mas antes é preciso arrumar a URL no arquivo de configuração do KCFinder. Tente procurar dentro da pasta **conf** o arquivo **config.php**. Daí lá você tem essa linha: `'uploadURL' => "upload"`. Você coloca a sua URL que vai determinar na rota.

Comment: Encontrei o arquivo de configuração e mudei `'uploadURL'=>"upload_imagens"`. Agora crio a rota: `Route::get('upload_imagens', ?);`. O que entraria no lugar de ?

Comment: Ah, agora entendi o que você quis dizer. O próprio KCFinder faz o Upload...

Comment: Encontrei isso no SOen: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36688258

Comment: Sim, mas quando clico no botãozinho de fazer upload de imagem, dá erro, diz q a rota não existe

Comment: Você conseguiu fazer ?

Comment: Acho que você tem que adicionar uma linha no *.htaccess* de dentro da pasta *public*. Antes dessa linha: `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]`, coloque essa: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/upload` que é a pasta do KCFinder fazer o upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema colocando a pasta do KCFinder dentro da pasta public do Laravel. Eu estava colocando dentro do pasta do CKEditor, por isso as URL's não funcionavam